# Adobe AIR and iOS

Tags: ios, air, adobe, flash-cs5

Is it possible to create an app using Flash and Adobe AIR that runs on iOS?  I thought Apple had eliminated the possibility of using Flash- does AIR have a solution?  What kind of problems are there?

Comment: This is what you are looking [Adobe AIR and iPhone - how it works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902840/adobe-air-and-iphone-how-it-worksClick)

Comment: Thanks, the responses are a little unclear, but it seems that using AIR may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create AIR applications for iOS. (What Apple doesn't allow is running Flash in a browser/web view.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Air cross platform for iOS and Android and also you can upload final product on app store.

Comment: You check above answer isn't same and you also you are not familiar for Adobe Air before answer me try to explore about  Adobe Air platform language. lol

Answer (score 0):

With adobe air you can compile and debug ios and android applications faster than other tools like xamarin,appcelerator etc.
Another benefit is that you are using same codes for both platforms
with Flashdevelop free ide you are just choosing platform when compiling apk or ipa.
Also you can develop ios applications on windows machine without xcode sdk.
You just need mac when uploading to applestore.
To install ipa to devices via usb you don't need mac or xcode.